# iPhone register for clock updates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nstimer, clock

A view in my application has a clock that I'd like to keep synced with the system. A number of Stack questions have centred around NSTimer, but before doing that, I want to check if there is a system notification I can register that is fired every minute.

Does such a thing exist? I'm looking through NSNotificationCenter but so far have nothing.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `NSTimer`'s `initWithFireDate` to fire on the minute by calculating the next change of the minute:

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"ss"];
int currentTimeSeconds = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate].intValue;

NSDate *fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60 - currentTimeSeconds];
NSTimer *updateTimer = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:fireDate
                                                 interval:60
                                                   target:self
                                                 selector:@selector(updateSelector)
                                                 userInfo:nil
                                                  repeats:YES];

NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
[runLoop addTimer:updateTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Comment: Great answer, but I'd use this to get the current seconds: `NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSTimeInterval currentTimeSeconds = (NSTimeInterval)[calendar component:NSCalendarUnitSecond fromDate:currentDate];`

Answer (score 2):

There is no `NSNotificationCenter` call that I know of that exists. It's really as simple as setting up an `NSTimer`. As long as you have set your `NSTimer` to **1 second** intervals you should be fine. Here is how I use the Time / Date in a label in one of my apps.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self 
                 selector:@selector(clockDateAndTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)clockDateAndTime:(NSTimer*)timer 
{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
    NSDate * date = [NSDate date];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
    [lblLocalDate setText:[formatter stringFromDate:date]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer of [beggs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11771148/1415713) above is right...here it is for swift:

```
let dateComp = self.calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnit.MonthCalendarUnit | NSCalendarUnit.YearCalendarUnit | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitSecond, fromDate: NSDate())
    dateComp.minute += 1
    dateComp.second = 0

    println(self.calendar.dateFromComponents(dateComp)!)
    let myTimer =  NSTimer(fireDate: self.calendar.dateFromComponents(dateComp)!, interval: 60, target: self, selector: "refreshCountdownNextMeal", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    let runloop = NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop()
    runloop.addTimer(myTimer, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
```

I don't have to tell you that calling a Timer once in a minute is better as 60 times a minute right? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A more literal swift 2 translation of @beggs answer:

```
let currentDate = NSDate()
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "ss";
let currentTimeSeconds = Double(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(currentDate))
let fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60 - currentTimeSeconds!)

let timer = NSTimer(fireDate: fireDate, interval: 60, target: self, selector: "minuteLoop", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(timer, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
```